# как сделать превью сайта при отсыланиии ссылки в месенджерах

Tags: веб-программирование, seo, браузер

Есть 2 сайта один принадлежит нам, а другой нет. При отсылании ссылки человеку в вк или телеграмм на чужом сайте отображается картинка-превью, а на нашем нет. Заходил на их сайт смотрел мета-тэги картинки той же самой не обнаружил. Хотелось бы узнать откуда берется эта картинка, скорее всего из кода сайта, а не из каких-то настроек самих месенджеров.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Прочитай про микроразметку и добавь на сайт scheme.org https://schema.org/
Также для каждой соц. сети есть разные стандарты микроразметки